# Expose Kubernete service to public inside mesosphere's DCOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, mesos, mesosphere

Followed https://www.mesosphere.com/amazon/ I created a DCOS cluster on Amazon AWS.
Then I followed http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/dcos.html and installed Kubernete on it.
Then I followed http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/quick-start.html
I was able to launch pods successfully.
Then I ran into problem with expose the service to public.

```
$ dcos kubectl expose rc my-nginx --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer
service "my-nginx" exposed
$ dcos ssun$ dcos kubectl get svc my-nginx
NAME       CLUSTER_IP    EXTERNAL_IP   PORT(S)   SELECTOR       AGE
my-nginx   10.10.10.32                 80/TCP    run=my-nginx   8s
```

The EXTERNAL_IP address does not exists. According to the tutorial, it should. So I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that my Kubernete is inside DCOS.

Please help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes on Mesos/DCOS does not support automatic LoadBalancer creation yet.

As the [quick start](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/quick-start.html) states:

> Through integration with some cloud providers (for example Google Compute Engine and AWS EC2), Kubernetes enables you to request that it provision a public IP address for your application.

AFAIK, only GCE, GKE, and AWS support automatic LoadBalancer creation so far.

Another key difference about DCOS (compared to kubernetes) is that it comes by default with two zones: public and private. So nothing scheduled on the private nodes is externally accessible without a reverse-proxy on the public nodes.

Additionally, Kubernetes on DCOS does not yet support IP-per-container. Support for IP-per-container is under development with the [DCOS/Calico integration](http://www.metaswitch.com/the-switch/metaswitch-mesosphere-work-on-project-calico-mesos-and-mesosphere-dcos-integration). Some community members have also reportedly attempted using cluster-wide docker overlay networking.

For now, there are a few alternative options for reaching your pod externally:

1. Deploy your pod on all the public slaves (using [resource role annotations](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/contrib/mesos/docs/scheduler.md#resource-roles)) and `hostPort:80`. Then hit the address of the DCOS public slave AWS ELB.
2. Create your own load balancer nginx pod (e.g. [service-loadbalancer](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/service-loadbalancer) and schedule it on the public slaves with `hostPort:80`. Then hit the IP of the host node it's on.

It's definitely a priority of the Mesosphere Kubernetes Team to make this experience smoother on DCOS. Hopefully the solution will include automatic LoadBalancer creation.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I though I only have 1 public slave which is the mesos master. How to make all slaves public slave?

Comment: When you create your DCOS cluster using AWS Cloud Formation there's 3 fields: how many masters, how many private slaves, and how many public slaves. Currently there's no easy way to use Cloud Formation to resize your cluster. So if you want a different configuration you'll have to recreate the cluster.